# can not read pathname error react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NewsContainer from './Components/NewsContainer';
import { Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light")

  const changeMode = () => {
    if (mode === "light") {
      setMode("dark")
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(30 41 59)"
    } else {
      setMode("light")
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    }
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='justify-evenly'>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<NewsContainer key="general" mode={mode} changeMode={changeMode} category="general" />} />
          <Route exact path='/sports' element={<NewsContainer key="sports" mode={mode} changeMode={changeMode} category="sports" />} />
          <Route exact path='/buisness' element={<NewsContainer key="buisness" mode={mode} changeMode={changeMode} category="buisness" />} />
          <Route exact path='/entertainment' element={<NewsContainer key="entertainment" mode={mode} changeMode={changeMode} category="entertainment" />} />
          <Route exact path='/health' element={<NewsContainer key="health" mode={mode} changeMode={changeMode} category="health" />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar({ mode, changeMode }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${mode === "light" ? "bg-gray-100" : "dark : bg-slate-900"} `}
    >
      <header className="text-gray-600 body-font">
        <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
          <li
            className={`flex title-font font-medium list-none items-center text-${
              mode === "light " ? "gray-900" : "white"
            } mb-4 md:mb-0 cursor-pointer`}
          >
            <span
              className={`ml-3 text-xl text-${
                mode === "light" ? "black" : "white"
              }`}
            >
              <Link to="/">Hind News</Link>
            </span>
          </li>
          <nav className="md:mr-auto md:ml-4 md:py-1 md:pl-4 md:border-l md:border-gray-400 flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center list-none cursor-pointer">
            <li
              className={`mr-5 hover:text-${
                mode === "light" ? "dark : gray-900" : "white"
              }`}
            >
              <Link to="/sport"> Sports </Link>
            </li>
            <li
              className={`mr-5 hover:text-${
                mode === "light" ? "dark : gray-900" : "white"
              }`}
            >
              <Link to="/buisness">Buisness </Link>
            </li>
            <li
              className={`mr-5 hover:text-${
                mode === "light" ? " dark:gray-900" : "white"
              }`}
            >
              <Link to="/entertainment">Entertainment </Link>
            </li>
            <li
              className={`mr-5 hover:text-${
                mode === "light" ? "dark : gray-900" : "white"
              }`}
            >
              <Link to="/health">Health </Link>
            </li>
          </nav>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="inline-flex items-center bg-gray-200 border-0 py-1 px-3 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-300 rounded text-base mt-4 md:mt-0"
          />
          <button className="inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 border-0 py-1 px-3 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-base mt-4 md:mt-0">
            Search
            <svg
              fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor"
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              className="w-4 h-4 ml-1"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <div className="flex justify-center">
              <div className="form-check form-switch">
                <input
                  className="form-check-input appearance-none w-9 -ml-10 rounded-full float-left h-5 align-top bg-white bg-no-repeat bg-contain bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none cursor-pointer shadow-sm ml-60"
                  type="checkbox"
                  role="switch"
                  id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                  onClick={changeMode}
                />
                <label
                  className={`form-check-label inline-block text-${
                    mode === "light" ? "gray-900" : "white"
                  } `}
                  htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                >
                  {" "}
                  Switch Mode
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Error on console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'pathname')
>
> The above error occurred in the `<Router>` component:
>
> ```
> at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39615:15)
> at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33:74)
> ```
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.

Comment: Could you share which version of `react-router` you are using?

Comment: react-router-dom 6.4 version @JonathanWieben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router) instead of [`Router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router#router), which is a wrapper around `Router`.

Comment: agree, just do BrowserRouter as Router in import statement.

Answer (score 1):

you got a typo in there.

```
<Link to="/sport"> Sports </Link>
```

when in the Route it spells sports

```
<Route exact path='/sports' element={<NewsContainer key="sports" mode={mode} changeMode={changeMode} category="sports" />} />
```

Hope it solves it

Comment: didn't work bro @Tomer_Ra

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are importing and rendering the low-level `Router` component and not passing any of the required props.

```
import { Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
```

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- missing
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;                 // <-- missing
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

Missing are the `location` and `navigator` props. The error is specifically due to the missing `location` prop, it's undefined, so the code can't access `pathname` of `undefined.

## Solution

You almost ***never*** need to render `Router` yourself manually. You should instead render one of the high-level routers (*e.g. `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc*) that instantiates and maintains a history reference and passes these required props to the low-level `Router` component.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```